# PHP PSR-1 via __call and __callStatic, is this too ugly?

Tags: php

I have one specific class in my project that have a lot of static and class methods (this is on purpose, it makes more sense, in this case, to use one big class instead of many smaller ones).

The methods were defined using underscore case like **method_name** instead of PSR-1 compliant **methodName** and we are converting a bunch of stuff to PSR-1.

Now, we could use something like these methods (below) to allow the usage of either one (method_name and methodName). The advantage is that we do not risk to introduce new bugs and all the current code using it still works, and we can migrate them slowly.

```
<?php

// enable PSR-1 for class methods
public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
    $toLower = function($c) { return '_'.strtolower($c[1]); };
    $underscoreCased = preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z])/', $toLower, $name);
    return forward_static_call_array(['ClassName', $underscoreCased], $args);
}

// enable PSR-1 for instance metods
public function __call($name, $args) {
    $toLower = function($c) { return '_'.strtolower($c[1]); };
    $underscoreCased = preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z])/', $toLower, $name);
    return call_user_func_array([$this, $underscoreCased], $args);
}
```

Now the question, is this too ugly? Should we avoid doing this despite the benefits listed above?

Comment: Seems a practicable workaround. Albeit a bit much effort for just naming convention compliance. -- The toLower function is redundant though, in this conversion direction anyway. (The PSR people would probably refuse to accept this, but method names are also case-insensitive in PHP.)

Comment: PSR-X are recommendation by Framework Interoperability Group (FIG). They are not laws of PHP, and most of the recommendations are not even good ideas. If you want check the quality of your code, you can use PHPMD, PHP CodeSniffer and PHP Depend tools. They will provide you with much better assessment of your coding practices, then recommendation by people, who wrote Drupal and PhpBB.

Comment: just copied and pasted some code for the sake of example. the naming convertion thing is actually a method somewhere. And this is an internal project, not even open source, so only people inside would use this work around.

Comment: We are trying to standardize the code base using one specific code convetion, the problem is that there are places using underscore case and others using cammel case.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it this way for several reasons:

1. Magic functions (`__call()`, `__callStatic()`, `__get()`, ...) are slow, really, really slow, [shown here](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magic-benchmarks)
2. Navigation: The class provides a method `do_something` but your code calls `Object::doSomething()`. This is an obstacle on my way to check the implementation, as I cannot simply Ctrl+F for `doSomething`. The same is true for IDEs and code completion.
3. Why migrating at all? I guess you have more important things to do than slowly migrating method names in an internal, private project to a nomenclature defined for interoperability with other projects. Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't say, that the PSRs are nonsense, I just think that old code doesn't have to be forced into complying unless it's absolutely necessary. (Which in this case means, that this particular class is the only class left *not* complying to it in your whole project)

So, basically my advice: If you really need to migrate this class to PSR-1, do it either all at once or let it be. But don't introduce magic functions only to comply to a naming scheme.